# Symfony 4 Beta - installing monolog then clearing cache produces a count() error

Tags: symfony, monolog

I am using the v4.0.0-BETA1 tag and when I run

```
composer req log
```

then

```
php bin/console cache:clear  --env=prod
```

I get the following error messages:

> In BaseNode.php line 348:
>
> Invalid configuration for path "monolog.handlers.main": Warning:
>   count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable
>
> In Configuration.php line 654:
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable

Uninstalling monolog

```
composer rem log
```

Allows the cache to be cleared successfully again. Any ideas on a fix here?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using php 7.2? Monolog doesn't support it. Here's a fix to be committed https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/223

Edit: It has already been fixed in 3.1.2: https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/releases/tag/v3.1.2

Comment: This answer provides a solution to the question - just add the commit that fixes the problem if you want to use it right now. Or wait till it's committed in the repository.